# JAI Memory usage is always 0KB

Tags: geoserver

In [server status page](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/configuration/status.html) I can see JAI Memory usage is always 0KB.

I already enabled [Tile Recycling](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/configuration/image_processing/index.html#jai).
Is it related to the JAI-EXT? I activated it using `-Dorg.geotools.coverage.jaiext.enabled=true` in startup script.

Why is it always 0KB? How much is the server performance impact and what can I do to force/make my server use JAI memory?

Comment: are you using any rasters?

Comment: Jesus iant! are you a bot? Give you a little time to a coffee. Good question... no. Just PostGIS vectors ...

Comment: Then you won't be using any jai so memory will stay at 0